# How can I verify that my Tomcat app server correctly supports FIPS 140-2?

Tags: tomcat, openssl, fips, apr

I've built openssl-fips, openssl, and tc-native ([Tomcat Native Library](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/)) and pointed Tomcat at the native library. I see APR started in the logs:

```
13-Nov-2014 14:01:32.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.32 using APR version 1.3.9.
13-Nov-2014 14:01:32.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
13-Nov-2014 14:01:32.431 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014)
13-Nov-2014 14:01:32.712 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-443"]
```

I can get to the site using `https://localhost/` and the cert looks like it's correct. Firefox looks the same when I look at the site security information and compare the before-FIPS and after-FIPS setup:

[image]

The questions are:

1. How can I verify that the communication between the browser and server is actually FIPS 140-2 compliant?
2. Is there any way to force FIPS-only communication on the server end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be obvious, but this isn't a `<Connector>` option, but instead an APR option which gets configured in the `APRLifecycleListener` in `CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`.

You can read the [documentation for the APRLifecycleListener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/listeners.html#APR_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener) and see that there is a `FIPSMode` setting that allows you to control the use of FIPS mode. I think you want `FIPSMode="on"`.

This will force Tomcat (really OpenSSL) to operate in a FIPS-compliant manner. The client has no effect on this, and will therefore have to conform to the server's (FIPS-compliant) behavior.

Comment: FWIW, FIPS-140-2 is pretty much irrelevant, though I know lots of people running US-government-related services are required to adhere to it. I personally don't believe FIPS-compliance buys you anything at all above and beyond what you get from any decent crypto library.

Comment: Hmm. I'll take a look at the APR options in the APRLifecycleListener. Thanks.

Comment: After enabling this option, I now see: "Initializing FIPS mode..." and "Successfully entered FIPS mode"